# Creating a record from a different model view(no new action involved)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-view-controller

I have a has_many & belongs_to associations between company and worker. I want to be able to add a worker to a company via a link in my workers index page. I want that to save the worker record belonging to the logged in company and update the company/workers index page with the new worker added to their workers.

I have been unable to do this. Here is what is happening:

My routes have something like:

```
  namespace :company do
    resources :workers, :only => [:index, :create]
  end

  resources :workers
```

I have a before_action method that has the cookie session with the company access token in my controllers:

ApplicationController:

```
@company = Company.find_by_access_token("vZAni6K6")
cookies[:access_token] = @company.access_token
```

And Company::WorkersController

```
render :file => "public/401.html", :layout => nil, :status => :unauthorized and return if cookies[:access_token] != @company.access_token
```

In my workers/index.html.haml path I have:

```
= "There are #{@workers.count} workers!"

They are:
- @workers.each do |worker|
  = worker.name
  = link_to "Hire a worker", company_workers_path(:worker_id => worker), :method => :post
%%br

%p= @company.name
```

I want the to be able to click the "Hire a worker link" and then be redirected to the company/workers.html.haml path that then will list their workers updated with the recent addition of the worker just added via the link.

When I currently click the link(say for worker #2 in by database) instead of taking me to company/workers path it takes me to

```
company/workers?worker_id=2
```

And it doesn't save the worker to the association with the company.

My company/workers controller has the following:

```
  def create
    @worker = @company.worker.build(:worker_id => params[:worker_id])
    @worker.save
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end
```

Remember I have a before_action on my controllers that saves the @company instance variable before calling other controller methods as well.

I have a model Worker that belongs_to a company & a model Company that has_many workers and I have added the reference key in my migration already.

What is the problem? Why the weird route and why are my records not saving, I am a bit of a newb so forgive the simple question.

Answer (score 0):

At first look, I see you may have two errors:

1. your Company model class has_many workers, so to assign (or add) a worker to a company I believe it must be something like:

   ```
   @worker = Worker.find(params[:worker_id])
   @worker.company = @company
   @worker.save!
   # depending in your schema, it could be something like this as well:
   # @company.workers << @worker
   ```
2. to redirect to company/workers, as you use nested routes, it must be like

   ```
   redirect_to company_workers_path(@company)
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This didn't solve the problem, now the url finished with company/workers.id    but still didn't save the worker to the company

Comment: could you put some code of your models? so I can see better your implementation.